# How to display a hindi language in browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having a mvc project in which there are dropdownlist.
the problem am facing is that,when I select the dropdownlist the content of the dropdownlist displays in english(although the data is in hindi language), but when I select any of the option from the dropdwon list then the data in list get displayed in hindi language.
But in google chrome it works fine, when I click the dropdwon list, the list gets displayed in hindi and also the selected option selected is displayed in  hindi.
Both of the browsers are up to date.
firefox 58.   Google chrome 63.

Comment: Can you share a piece of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `meta charset` in your `head` tag?

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```